# Further questions on hatcheck problem: what is the probability of r people receiving the correct hat?

Tags: probability

Since the original hatcheck problem is really famous and many questions have been posted on the forum, I think I can safely skip the context part.

Note that, the probability of exactly one man receives the correct hat is 1/n, this can be solved by using **the linearity of expectations**. Moreover, no man receives correct hat is a derangement, which can be solved by **inclusion-exclusion principle.**

Now, to take a step further, if we are to calculate the probability of **exactly r man** receives the correct hat, how can we exploit the information we have already have to derive a simpler answer? Since all the materials online seems to be particularly interested in the above two cases, I feel rather confused.

Comment: Well, phrasing the problem is never a bad idea, all the more if you are introducing variations or additional structure.

Comment: "*The* **probability** *of exactly one man receives the correct hat is $\frac{1}{n}$, this can be solved by using the linearity of expectation*"  No.  Linearity of expectation is useful for calculating *expected values*, not probabilities.  The probability of no men getting their correct hat is $\dfrac{!n}{n!}$.  The probability of one man receiving their correct hat is $\dfrac{n\cdot !(n-1)}{n!}$ and in general of exactly $k$ men receiving their correct hat is $\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}\cdot !(n-k)}{n!}$ seen by first choosing the $k$ people and then deranging the remaining $n-k$ people.

Comment: Going back to expected value, the expected number of correct hats taken back is going to be $n\times \frac{1}{n}=1$.  Going from this to the probability of one man getting their correct hat is not done, they are completely different calculations.  Perhaps the $\frac{1}{n}$ you were referring to was the probability that the first person gets their hat back (*regardless of whether or not anyone else gets their correct hat back*)